# What is the difference between "yarn serve" and "yarn start" and "yarn build"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, frontend, yarnpkg

I only know that "yarn serve" and "yarn start" can both get my vue project up and running, but I don't know what the difference is between the two.

All I know about "yarn build" is that it's a "packaging" method, but what is packaging and why do I never use it at work? I usually just upload my code to git and my backend colleagues can publish it on the web（I don't know what's going on here. ）

（I think my question description has been very clear, why should I close my question, I have nothing to add）

Answer (score 2):

`yarn serve` and `yarn start` both run scripts defined in your package.json (probably, more info required to be sure.) that do the same thing.

> but what is packaging and why do I never use it at work?

Packaging means removing all (npm) packages that are *not* required in production. It can also run scripts to minimize, obfuscate and compile Javascript or (S)CSS files. In the end you will end up with a, hopefully, smaller bundle of .js, .css and .html files that can be hosted.